# Visualization of missing records in DataFrame

Tags: pandas

Visualization of missing records in DataFrame

I have a lot of missing dataframe records.

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

The problem is that these deficiencies are connected and I don't know how to see them. Because I do not want to mess up so as to spoil data. What are your ways to see the structure of the missing dataframe?

Comment: I think you should specify what you mean by "connected" deficiencies. Regarding your question, you might find `df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]` useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use such plot of concentration

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(df.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.info()`. It will give you non null record count in each column.